# Removing a subtring from a string

Tags: c++, string

I have a string which represents a file name, and I want to remove the extension, so erasing everything after the ".". What would be the best way ? Thanks.

Comment: Please show some of what you tried when you ask for help.

Comment: Well, how about `file.tar.gz` do you need to handle this as well?

Answer (score 2):

Below code can be used for the same..

```
int npos = str.find_last_of('.');
str = str.substring(0,npos);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, the following function will do the trick:

```
std::wstring StripFileExtension(std::wstring fileName)
{
  WCHAR tempBuffer[MAX_PATH];

  if (fileName.empty())
  {
    return TEXT("");
  }

  wcscpy(tempBuffer, fileName.c_str());
  PathRemoveExtension(tempBuffer);

  return tempBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks all, since I'm on Windows I'll use this "ready" function.

Comment: @user2370139 Please accept my answer, then. I'm glad that'll work for you!

Comment: @user2370139 That is quite short-sighted. If you can write portable code, why write non-portable one?

Comment: @juanchopanza While that's often accurate, I think it largely depends on your use-case. I pulled that function from a Windows-only app I maintain, which is heavily tied to the Windows API. In this case, I'd rather know I'm providing standard behavior for the OS than provide portable code. I can't speak for user2370139's use-case, of course.

Answer (score 0):

you can use std::string , and copy each character to new string

```
std::string name = "filename.jpg", newname ="";
int thelength = 0;
for(int i=name.length();i>0;i--){
    if( name[i] != '.'){
           thelength++;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<(name.length()-thelength);i++){
    newname+=name[i];
}
```

Comment: How is it answer to OP question ?

Comment: i forgot to check the '.'

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question properly; filenames with two extensions will lose them both. That might not be intended behavior depending on what the asker needs.

Comment: Still not there... you'll copy the "real" file extension (and backwards at that, it looks like) but drop everything before it.